# Storing images into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a searchable array in JS. I want the arrays to work as only the images show, then using 'tags' to filter and search this array.

If I were to have something along the lines of this:

```
function NotebookListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.notebooks = [
    {"name": "Lenovo",
     "processor": "Intel i5",
     "age": 2011},

//more notebooks... 

    {"name": "Toshiba",
     "processor": "Intel i7",
     "age": 2010},
  ];
  $scope.orderList = "name";
}
```

Is there a way I can use something along the lines of...

```
notebooks[0] = new Image();
notebooks[0].src = 'images/img/image1.jpg';
```

So when notebooks item [0] is displayed, it will show the image along with it?
Relatively new to JS and am trying to piece something together. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No need to create a new image. This has more to do with html and displaying of the image than anything else:

```
function NotebookListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.notebooks = [
    {"name": "Lenovo",
     "processor": "Intel i5",
     "age": 2011,
     "src": 'images/img/image1.jpg'
    },

//more notebooks... 

    {"name": "Toshiba",
     "processor": "Intel i7",
     "age": 2010,
     "src": 'images/img/image2.jpg'
    },
  ];
  $scope.orderList = "name";
}

<div 
     ng-repeat="notebook in notebooks | orderby: orderList">
    <p>name: {{notebook.name}}</p>
    <p>processor: {{notebook.processor}}</p>
    <p>age: {{notebook.age}}</p>
    <img 
         ng-if="notebook.src"
         ng-src="{{notebook.src}}">
</div>
```

Just set the image source and use the ng-src attribute in html to set the image source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I never thought of it this way. What is the load time looking at for doing this method, to say 100 images..? Would I be able to implement a lazyload into this if using this method?

Comment: This is under the assumption you use angular (which is a beast on its own if you never used JS before)

Comment: I have never used angular, I figured I should get a handle on regular JS. I took a few classes in college, but it never stuck since I'm more front end / graphic design and just picked up HTML/CSS for fun.

Comment: @user4470749 Your example code in the question is Angular.js code.

Comment: I am forking someone on codepen to get an idea of how to go about this. He must have used it, which would explain why a few of my things on the pen are not working.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. I assumed you were using angular because of your code in question. Either way, my answer still stands. no need to instantiate a new Image(). html handles that with src. I'd still suggest using a templating engine like handlebars to do this.

Comment: Read this about handlebars and js: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-handlebars--net-27761

Comment: Also, this should work perfectly fine if you actually just install angular and create a controller.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that, thanks for all the answers, looks like I have some work to do!

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be avoid using Image object, unless you need to pre-load your images in your JS code, and only store the img src path for each product in your array like in:

```
 $scope.notebooks = [
    {"name": "Lenovo",
     "processor": "Intel i5",
     "age": 2011
     "img": "images/img/image1.jpg"    
    },
// ...
```

Then in your img tag you can just point to the source of each product accordingly.

You can configure your web server to tell the browser to cache the images so it would enhance img loading time.

Comment: Image object outside of this could be usefull if you want to preload some images.

Comment: @Drifter yes and you can also make your server tell the browser to cache certain image types using Expires Headers, would make it faster next time user lands on the page.